# In Swift, how to make a dynamic tableView cell selectable so when it is pressed it transfers to a different tableViewController?

Tags: swift, tableview, segue, uitableview

I have a tableView with dynamic cells that when the cell is pressed I want it to transfer to a different tableViewController through a segue.  I figured out how to do it by pressing a button on the cell but not if the cell itself is pressed. I'm stumped, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this should be the function you are looking for `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

Comment: I tried using  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.dismissSearchBar()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("channelToShowSegue", sender: self)
  }

Comment: Didn't work means the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath ` didn't get call or the inner `performSegueWithIdentifier("channelToShowSegue", sender: self)` didn't work?

Comment: When the cell is pressed the performSegueWithIndentifier does nothing.  But when the performSegueWithIdentifier is called under an IBAction it works.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just control-dragging from the cell to the view controller in IB? Then the segue will happen automatically and you just need to set up any data requirement in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: I can only get an IBOutlet if I control + drag.  Not an IBAction to call the segue.

Comment: You don't drag to code - you drag from the cell to the other view controller. Then you get a "selection segue" popup where you can select the type of segue you want. This is the normal way to hook up cells to view controllers so you get a nice visual representation in IB.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, you have to put `tableView.allowsSelection = true` in the cellForRowAtIndexPath first before calling DidSelectRowAtIndexPath.